# Zookeeper stat command confusion

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have 3-node zookeeper cluster. `10.0.0.1`, `10.0.0.2`, `10.0.0.3`. After starting running. `10.0.0.3` has been elected as Leader. When I try to get the status of the node with command `stat`, outputs like below:

```
Zookeeper version: 3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT
Clients:
 /127.0.0.1:60380[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
 /10.0.0.3:60292[1](queued=0,recved=44074,sent=44131)
 /10.0.0.1:51500[1](queued=0,recved=6287950,sent=6288007)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/45
Received: 7595959
Sent: 7596074
Connections: 3
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0xd000013a9
Mode: leader
Node count: 1712
Proposal sizes last/min/max: 32/32/5109
```

Run the same command on `10.0.0.1` will output like

```
Zookeeper version: 3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT
Clients:
 /10.0.0.3:47832[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
 /10.0.0.1:54326[1](queued=0,recved=6664230,sent=6664344)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/31
Received: 13802470
Sent: 13802583
Connections: 2
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0xd000013a9
Mode: follower
Node count: 1712
```

On `10.0.0.2`, outputs like below:

```
Zookeeper version: 3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT
Clients:
 /10.0.0.3:47766[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/8
Received: 1058
Sent: 1057
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0xd000013a9
Mode: follower
Node count: 1712
```

I'm confused with the `Clients` block in both 3 outputs. Why did they look different? Is there anyone know what is the mechanism in Zookeeper `stat` to show the `Clients` block? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `Clients` block is just showing the client connections.  When you connect to ZooKeeper, you don't connect to every server, you can connect to any server.  So to interpret your `stat` output:

- The leader at `10.0.0.3` has 3 client connections
- follower 1 at `10.0.0.1` has 2 connections
- follower 2 at `10.0.0.2` has 1 connection

For reference you can look at [StatCommand.java](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/command/StatCommand.java).